# DataTable to List wiring generic method

Tags: c#, .net, generic-list, generic-collections

```
 public static List<T> DataTable2List(DataTable dt, int index)
 {
            List<T> lst = new List<T>();
            lst = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable() select Convert.ChangeType(row[0], typeof(T))).ToList();
            return lst;
 }
```

Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

How to get rid of the error. And I dont want the genericness of the function.

Comment: How you want to use this method?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public static List<T> DataTable2List<T>(DataTable dt, int index) where T : IConvertible 
{
    List<T> lst = new List<T>();
    lst = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable() select (T)Convert.ChangeType(row[0], typeof(T))).ToList();
    return lst;
}
```

> And I dont want the genericness of the function.

Huh? You want to use a type `T` which is generic without using generics? No way.

Comment: Could you potentially use `row[0].GetType()`? Just a thought.